# jQuery toggle national flag

Tags: jquery

I have this small problem with jQuery toggle(). I'm quite sure that i'm missing something in my code but I don't know what. My problem is that I can't get the flag change working as I want. Basically idea is that when I click flag, it changes the language and the flag. Language changes everytime, but the flag doesn't.

Here is my code.

```
<span class="tog">
 <?php echo "<a href=?lang=1"."><img class='flags' src='images/Flag1.png'></a>";?>      
 <?php echo "<a href=?lang=2"."><img class='flags' style='display:none' src='images/Flag2.png'> </a>";?>
</span>
<script>
 $(".tog").click(function(){
  $('img', this).toggle();
 });
</sript>
```

When there is the href and I change language at my page the flag1 doesn't toggle off, and stays allways on when it should change the Flag2 instead.

Is there better way to do this than toggle or am I missing something crucial.

Comment: you are refreshing the page, after page load, jquery will execute again and will set to default flag

Comment: As @charankumar said you are refreshing page. So you can check the $_GET before script gets the point where it echos flag and add codition if($_GET['lang'] == 1) to show the right flag.

Comment: Put the `lang` attribute on the `html` tag, in PHP or whatever server-side language you use: `<html lang="en">...</html>`. Show one flag or another, in *jquery*, based on the value of the `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(".tog a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.tog').toggleClass('second');
 });
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
.flags.second {
  display: none;
}
.tog.second .flags.second {
  display: block;
}

.tog.second .flags.first {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tog">
 <a href=?lang=1"."><img class='flags first' src='https://theflagcompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/indianNationlFlag-600x600.jpg'></a>
 <a href=?lang=2"."><img class='flags second'  src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png'> </a>
</span>
```